# Does Arrays.binarySearch give me a right position of a non-contained element?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I would like to use the fastest way to insert new elements into a sorted array and the array must be sorted after insertion. So I have planned that I use `System.arrayCopy`, but sometimes I compute the wrong interval positions.

Here is my code:

```
int[] res; // filled with random numbers and sorted
int old; // the old value which I want to remove
int now; // the new value which I want to insert

int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(res, 0, res.length, old);
int idy = Arrays.binarySearch(res, 0, res.length, now);

if (0 > idy) { // the new value has not been in the array

    idy = -idy - 1;
}
if (res.length == idy) {

    idy -= 1;
}

if (idx < idy) {
    //                       old             now
    // --------------------- idx ----------- idy -----------
    System.arraycopy(res, idx + 1, res, idx, idy - idx);
} else if (idx > idy) {
    //                       now             old
    // --------------------- idy ----------- idx -----------
    System.arraycopy(res, idy, res, idy + 1, idx - idy);
}
res[idy] = now;
```

Javadoc of `Arrays.binarySearch` says: it returns index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element in the range greater than the key, or `toIndex` if all elements in the range are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be `>= 0` if and only if the key is found.

I insert random integers [0..199], the array size of res is 666.

Sporadically the sorting of the array will be wrong after I insert about 5000-10000 new random integer.

I thank you for any advice. I don't need another solution like re-sorting again and again, because I want to use `System.arrayCopy` instead of `Arrays.sort`.

> NOTE: If it works, it's 1000 times faster than `Arrays.stream(...).sorted()`, and 100 times faster than re-shorting with `Arrays.sort`

Comment: What prevents you from writing a test case that does nothing but add/remove values, and checks after each insert for a valid sorted array? In other words: the first  thing to do would be to identify an example that fails. It might be worth looking at property based checking, too (like: https://github.com/pholser/junit-quickcheck ) ... actually, this is a perfect use case for such kind of testing.

Comment: I didn't test, but the bug might be in the `res.length == idy` case. By the way you could speed up the second binary sort a bit, if you compare old with new and then only search there (before or after idx).

Comment: This QuickCheck seems a very powerful tool, I will examine it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old index is before the new index, then the actual new insert position is one less. In code:

```
void replace(int[] sorted, int oldValue, int newValue) {
    int oldI = Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, 0, sorted.length, oldValue);
    if (oldI < 0) { // Nothing to replace?
        return;
    }
    int newI = Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, 0, sorted.length, newValue);
    if (newI < 0) {
        newI = ~newI; // Insert position (when oldI not removed).
    }
    if (oldI < newI) { // oxxxx[n]
        --newI;
        System.arraycopy(sorted, oldI + 1, sorted, oldI, newI - oldI);
    } else if (oldI > newI) { // [n]xxxxo (newI points to first x).
        System.arraycopy(sorted, newI, sorted, newI + 1, oldI - newI);
    }
    sorted[newI] = newValue;
}
```

The invert operator `~` is the same as `x -> -x - 1`.

Comment: It seems legit.